# Numeric comparison counterbalancing problem across a set of arrays with varying length (long post)

Tags: python, arrays

I need help with a problem regarding a graduate school project in Python.

- I have a list of numbers [90,120,150,180,210,240]
- I also have a list of 24 arrays of varying lengths. The possible lengths of the arrays are [3,6,9]
- Within the list of 24 arrays, each length appears precisely 8 times.
- Each array can have a starting element of the middle numbers of the total set [120,150,180,210]
- Each starting element appears twice for each array length such that each starting element interacts with 30 'zeros' and there are 120 zeros total, which looks like this:

```
    array([array([120,   0,   0]), array([120,   0,   0]),
           array([150,   0,   0]), array([150,   0,   0]),
           array([180,   0,   0]), array([180,   0,   0]),
           array([210,   0,   0]), array([210,   0,   0]),
           array([120,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([120,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([150,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([150,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([180,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([180,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([210,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([210,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([120,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([120,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([150,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([150,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([180,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([180,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([210,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
           array([210,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0])], dtype=object)
```

- I got the set of arrays shown above with:

```
    def gen_blank_arrays(stim_counts, sc_reps):
        blanks = []
        for sc in stim_counts:
            for i in range(sc_reps):
                blanks.append(np.zeros(sc, dtype = int))
        return np.asarray(blanks, dtype = object)
    
    def ret_inner_len(array):
        return np.asarray([len(inner) for inner in array])
    
    def ins_starting_num(blanks, SCs, starters):
        reps = (int((len(blanks)/len(SCs))/len(starters)))
        
        sc3 = np.where(ret_inner_len(blanks) == 3)[0]
        i = 0
        for s in starters:
            for x in range(reps):
                blanks[sc3[i]][0] = s
                i+=1
        sc6 = np.where(ret_inner_len(blanks) == 6)[0]
        i = 0
        for s in starters:
            for x in range(reps):
                blanks[sc6[i]][0] = s
                i+=1
        sc9 = np.where(ret_inner_len(blanks) == 9)[0]
        i = 0
        for s in starters:
            for x in range(reps):
                blanks[sc9[i]][0] = s
                i+=1
    
    SCs = [3,6,9]
    starters = [120,150,180,210]
    blanks = gen_blank_arrays(SCs, 8)
    ins_starting_num(blanks, SCs, starters)
```

- At this point, I need to populate the rest of the 0 elements with numbers from the full list of numbers mentioned above (see first bullet). I need to populate the 0 elements such that, when any element is compared with the first element of a subarray, I have an equal number of numeric distances [120, 90, 60, 30] and an equal number of "first element greater" comparisons and "first element lesser" comparisons in the entire parent array. This means every numeric distance will appear 15 times with a greater first element and 15 times with a lesser first element.
- Here is the total set of possible comparisons:

```
    {'first_greater_120ND': [(210, 90)],
     'first_lesser_120ND': [(120, 240)],
     'first_greater_90ND': [(180, 90), (210, 120)],
     'first_lesser_90ND': [(120, 210), (150, 240)],
     'first_greater_60ND': [(150, 90), (180, 120), (210, 150)],
     'first_lesser_60ND': [(120, 180), (150, 210), (180, 240)],
     'first_greater_30ND': [(120, 90), (150, 120), (180, 150), (210, 180)],
     'first_lesser_30ND': [(120, 150), (150, 180), (180, 210), (210, 240)]}
```

- I tried to solve this problem with this code:

```
    #returns the dictionary shown above
    def get_possible_comparisons(numeric_distances, starters, allnum):
        
        #set comparison conditions by first>/first< and desired numeric distances
        possible_comparisons = {}
        for nd in numeric_distances:
            possible_comparisons.update({f"first_greater_{nd}ND": []})
            possible_comparisons.update({f"first_lesser_{nd}ND": []})
        
        #find all possible comparisons that satisfy the conditions
        for s in starters:
            for an in allnum:
                if s>an and abs(s-an) in numeric_distances:
                    nd = abs(s-an)
                    possible_comparisons[f"first_greater_{nd}ND"].append((s,an))
                elif s<an and abs(s-an) in numeric_distances:
                    nd = abs(s-an)
                    possible_comparisons[f"first_lesser_{nd}ND"].append((s,an))
        
        return possible_comparisons

    
    #returns the first element of the subarray
    def ret_inner_index(array, index = 0):
        return np.asarray([a[index] for a in array])
    
    #attempts to populate the rest of the zeros
    def ins_conditions(possible_conditions, blanks, reps = 15):
        for pc, values in possible_conditons.items():
            for i in range(reps):
                
                c = random.choice(values)
                s = c[0]
                insert = c[1]
                        
                matching_indicies = np.where(ret_inner_index(blanks)==s)[0]
             
                insert_indicies = []
                for match in matching_indicies:
                    zeros = np.where(blanks[match] == 0)[0]
                    for zero in zeros:
                        insert_indicies.append((match, zero))
    
                x, y = random.choice(insert_indicies)
    
    NDs = [120, 90, 60, 30]
    starters = [120,150,180,210]
    allnum = [90,120,150,180,210,240]
    SCs = [3,6,9]
    
    possible_conditons = get_possible_comparisons(
        NDs,
        starters,
        allnum
    )
    
    ins_conditions(possible_conditons, blanks)
```

- The issue with this code is that it picks possible comparisons randomly, however as I've discovered, the number of possible comparisons can only appear in certain combinations. So I end up getting an IndexError at x, y = random.choice(insert_indicies).
- Here is one such possible combination that I got by hand:

```
    {'first_greater_120ND': [(210, 90) = 15 reps,],
     'first_lesser_120ND': [(120, 240) = 15 reps,],
     'first_greater_90ND': [(180, 90) = 8 reps, (210, 120) = 7 reps],
     'first_lesser_90ND': [(120, 210) = 7 reps, (150, 240) = 8 reps],
     'first_greater_60ND': [(150, 90) = 5 reps, (180, 120) = 5 reps, (210, 150) = 5 reps],
     'first_lesser_60ND': [(120, 180) = 5 reps, (150, 210) = 5 reps, (180, 240) = 5 reps],
     'first_greater_30ND': [(120, 90) = 1 rep, (150, 120) = 6 reps, (180, 150) = 6 reps, (210, 180) = 2 reps],
     'first_lesser_30ND': [(120, 150) = 2 reps, (150, 180) = 6 reps, (180, 210) = 6 reps, (210, 240) = 1 rep]}
     
     210 starter comparisons = 15 + 7 + 5 + 2 + 1 = 30
     180 starter comparisons = 8 + 5 + 5 + 6 + 6 = 30
     150 starter comparisons = 8 + 5 + 5 + 6 + 6 = 30
     120 starter comparisons = 15 + 7 + 5 + 1 + 2 = 30
```

- And there are many other possible combinations. I want to populate the rest of the elements while choosing a possible combination randomly, however I'm stuck trying to figure out how to program a function to populate these elements while remaining constrained to the possible combinations.

Sorry for the long post. I tried to include everything necessary to understand the problem. Any insight or help as to how I can achieve this is much appreciated!

Comment: You'd probably do yourself (and anyone trying to understand your problem) a favour by simplifying the problem (fewer numbers and arrays) and providing an example solution to that simpler problem. A solution should then scale up. Part of why your problem is hard to understand is that you don't provide any information about why you're trying to fill this list of arrays according to the rules presented here. What exactly is the problem you're really solving? Isn't your question really more of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Apart from the above, the main thing that I'm missing in your explanation is why the data is separated into the arrays of length 3, 6 and 9 - there seem to be no constraints specifically related to these sizes, so why aren't the simply combined?

Comment: @Grismar This is mainly a counterbalancing problem in which I have to counterbalance the variables of multiple conditions. These conditions are: array size, starting element, numeric distance of starting element compared to other elements in a subarray, whether the starting element is larger or smaller compared to other elements in the subarray. My task requires me to have an equal number of these variables within the entire parent array. Ie: there are 3 possible array lengths and 24 arrays, therefore each array length has to appear 8 times.

Comment: So there really is no application, it's just a problem for the sake of the problem?